# How do I position an SCNCamera such that an object "just fits" in view?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, scenekit

I am making a 3D board game using SceneKit. The board itself is flat, but the pieces on it are 3D. I want to position the camera such that it is looking down at the board at an angle like this:

```
                camera
               /
              /
             /
            /
           /
board     /
___________
```

I want to position the camera such that the entire board is in view, and not small. I know the board's dimensions at runtime, but not at compile time though, because the user can choose from many different boards to play the game.

I tried to calculate how far the camera will at least have to be to see the full width of the board. I drew a diagram like this:

[image]

and worked out that the distance is the half the width of the board divided by tan(FOV/2).

Translating that to code:

```
private func setupCamera(boardWidth: CGFloat, maxBoardZ: CGFloat, boardCenterX: CGFloat) {
    cameraNode = SCNNode()
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.camera = camera

    let boardRadius = boardWidth / 2
    let cameraDistance = boardRadius / tan(degreesToRadians(camera.fieldOfView) / 2)
    let cameraHeight: Float = 10

    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: Float(boardCenterX), y: cameraHeight, z: Float(maxBoardZ + cameraDistance))

    cameraNode.eulerAngles.x = -0.5
}
```

`cameraNode` is a property of the scene to which I later set the scene view's `pointOfView` to.

This looks okay on portrait mode (this is only a portion of the whole phone screen):

[image]

The camera couldn't have moved much closer to the board without cutting off parts of the board.

But in landscape, the board is extremely small compared to the `SCNView` that it is in:

[image]

The camera could have moved a lot closer! I would have expected something like:

[image]

Notice the white background region - that's the `SCNView`.

I thought the FOV might have changed in landscape, but when I checked in the debugger, the FOV is always 60 degrees, no matter the orientation. It seems like even though `SCNCamera` has a `fieldOfView` property, `SCNView` also has its own, separate, FOV that depends on its width and height, and I have no idea how to access it.

How can I position the camera such that the whole board *just* fits inside the `SCNView`?

Comment: It's just a personal oninion, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @ElTomato That's fine. Frame challenge answers are welcome :)

Comment: Similar issue, had 90 maps various sizes - tricky stuff.  Move closer, make the panels bigger - trial and error.  Eventually, I created a tool to build the maps using the game camera settings.  For me, that was the way to go.  For larger maps, I added strafe with limits based on max width of "that" map - that worked pretty well.  Painful, but you only have so much real estate to work with and with a tool, you get it right the first time you build a map.  Doesn't answer your question, but I can share the camera class if you want it.

Comment: @Voltan not OP but I would be very interested in that!

Comment: @Voltan You mean you created the map based on the camera position, rather than position the camera based on the map? That's an interesting idea! I see, so you moved the camera much closer, and didn't mind not showing the whole map because you had strafe controls. (Did I understand correctly?) I want to keep my camera controller simple - orbit around the y axis about the centre of the map _only_, so I kind of have to show the whole map in its entirety.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was away.  Yes, per the answer below - I show the whole map too.  I just get the ideal distance with the map tool for a visual, then I don't build outside the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - posting it here - hope that's ok.

I used strafe just for a couple of big maps, but eventually took them out.  I wanted all of the maps to fit - it looks very similar to yours. So yeah, I worked backwards.  I put the camera where I wanted it, then fiddled with the map and panel size, so I was only dealing with one thing at a time.

I had panels for triangles, quads, and hex shapes.  It was a tower defense game, so the attackers could move various ways depending on the type of panel.

```
class Camera
{
    var data = Data.sharedInstance
    var util = Util.sharedInstance
    var gameDefaults = Defaults()
    
    var cameraEye = SCNNode()
    var cameraFocus = SCNNode()
        
    var centerX: Int = 100
    var strafeDelta: Float = 0.8
    var zoomLevel: Int = 35
    var zoomLevelMax: Int = 35              // Max number of zoom levels
    
    //********************************************************************
    init()
    {
        cameraEye.name = "Camera Eye"
        cameraFocus.name = "Camera Focus"
        
        cameraFocus.isHidden = true
        cameraFocus.position  =  SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        
        cameraEye.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraEye.constraints = []
        cameraEye.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 15, z: 0.1)
        
        let vConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cameraFocus)
        vConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
        cameraEye.constraints = [vConstraint]
    }
    //********************************************************************
    func reset()
    {
        centerX = 100
        cameraFocus.position  =  SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        cameraEye.constraints = []
        cameraEye.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 32, z: 0.1)
        cameraFocus.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        
        let vConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cameraFocus)
        vConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
        cameraEye.constraints = [vConstraint]
    }
    //********************************************************************
    func strafeRight()
    {
        if(centerX + 1 < 112)
        {
            centerX += 1
            cameraEye.position.x += strafeDelta
            cameraFocus.position.x += strafeDelta
        }
    }
    //********************************************************************
    func strafeLeft()
    {
        if(centerX - 1 > 90)
        {
            centerX -= 1
            cameraEye.position.x -= strafeDelta
            cameraFocus.position.x -= strafeDelta
        }
    }
    //********************************************************************
}
```

I used GKGraph like this:

```
var graphNodes: [GKPanelNode] = [] // All active graph nodes with connections
var myGraph = GKGraph()   // declaring the Graph
```

Then your typical panel load, probably similar to yours

```
func getQuadPanelNode(vPanelType: panelTypes) -> SCNNode
    {
        let plane = SCNBox(width: 1.4, height: 0.001, length: 1.4, chamferRadius: 0)
        
        plane.materials = []
        plane.materials = setQuadPanelTextures(vPanelType: vPanelType)
        plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = false
        return SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    }
```

Then load the panels from the map I created.

```
func loadPanels()
    {
        removePanelNodes()
        for vPanel in mapsDetail.getDetail(vMap: data.mapSelected)
        {
            let vPanel = Panel.init(vName: "Panel:" + vPanel.name, vPanelType: vPanel.type, vPosition: vPanel.pos, vRotation: vPanel.up)
            gridPanels[vPanel.panelName] = vPanel
            
            if(vPanel.type == .entry) { entryPanelName = vPanel.panelName }
            if(vPanel.type == .exit)  { exitPanelName  = vPanel.panelName }
        }
    }
```